# Data Not inserting into table PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The data is not inserting  into another table, here's the code below :

```
if (isset($_POST))
    {
        $job = $_POST['jobtitle'];
        $dur = $_POST['duration'];
        $deg = $_POST['requireddegree'];
        $exp = $_POST['experiance'];
        $sal = $_POST['salary'];
        $mark = $_POST['marks'];


        if ( !empty($job) && !empty($dur) && !empty($deg) && !empty($exp) && !empty($sal) && !empty($mark))
        {
            $dur = mysql_real_escape_string($dur);
            $deg= mysql_real_escape_string($deg);
            $exp = mysql_real_escape_string($exp);
            $sal = mysql_real_escape_string($sal);
            $mark = mysql_real_escape_string($mark);
            $job = mysql_real_escape_string($job);



            $query="INSERT INTO jobposting (duration,degree,experiance,salary,marks,Jobtitle) VALUES ('".$dur."','".$deg."','".$exp."','".$sal."','".$mark."','".$job."') ";

            if ($query_run= mysql_query($query))
            {
                header('location : Main.html');
            }
            else
            {
                echo ' Data not Inserted! ';    
            }

        }
```

With this it gives me server error or there was an error in CGI script.But when I write the variables in this form '$dur' instead of '".$dur." then the else conditon runs after insert query and displays data is not inserted.

However, i have written the same logic  while inserting data in my another table and it inserts successfully.But there I put '$dur'.

I can't find the problem.Will be glad for your suggestions :)

Comment: `"it gives me server error"` - Well, what's the error?  Check your PHP logs, your web server logs, turn on error reporting in PHP, check `mysql_error()`, etc.  You need to find out what the error *is* in order to correct it.

Comment: Also, for PHP, strings in double quotes can include variables, so ... VALUES ('$dur', '$deg', '$exp',   ... will work and is easier to read.  I've also found it helpful to echo my query string (temporarily while debugging) and paste it into SQL console or phpMyAdmin

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql api

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find any other error by seeing this code expect for

```
$query="INSERT INTO jobposting (duration,degree,experiance,salary,marks,Jobtitle) VALUES ('$dur','$deg','$exp','$sal','$mark','$job') ";

//Use ".$job." only for stuff like '".md5($_POST['password'])."' otherwise this creates problem some times.

// Adding this always helps
if(!mysqli_query($con,$query))
 {
  die('error'.mysqli_error($con));
 }
 // in $con = $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
 else
 {
   if ($query_run= mysql_query($query))
     {
       header('location : Main.html');
      }
    else
    {
      echo ' Data not Inserted! ';    
    }

 }
```

I think by making these changes and making sure that your db name and other basic stuff are correct then you should be good to go otherwise, specify your exact error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have now noticed that the data is inserting, the error was in header ('location: Main.html'); A foolish mistake tough  ..Its done now :)

Comment: Yeah, the code looked fine that's why I said to check it again. When you are new these sort of mistakes happen.